# How to exclude some files from srcDir in a sourceSet?

Tags: android-studio, android-productflavors

I am Android Developer. I want create app in two flavour Free and Paid. But my requirement is whenever use Paid version then only Login.java should be call from Paid and rest of file should call from Free.

1). I tried following method but all file call from Free flavour.

```
sourceSets {
        paid {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/free/java']
            }
        }
    }
```

2). Tried with exclude. In this method showing error 'Login.java' not found.

```
sourceSets {
        paid {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/free/java']
                exclude 'package/Login.java'
            }
        }
    }
```

This is project structure. What is doing wrong please help.

```
src
 |
 +-Free
 |  |
 |  +-java
 |     |
 |     +-package
 |        |
 |        +- Utils.java
 |        +- Login.java
 |        +- Test.java 
 +-Paid
    |
    +-java
       |
       +-package
          |
          +- Login.java
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: suppose i have app with multiple flavour and i want set all common java code for all flavour except one java file. because i want store different configuration for  different flavour in this file.